# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1} e^{- \sqrt x} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

Test the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1} e^{- \sqrt x} dx$$

**Attempt:** For sufficiently large $x$, we have $e^{-\sqrt x} > e ^{- x}$.

I also tried solving the integral by By Parts rule, which resulted in a more hodgepodge.

Unfortunately, these methods did not prove to be of much help.

Please guide me on how to go about this problem.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Since the integrand is positive, this is the same as testing the convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{x}} \,dx$.

Comment: Ohh!! I just lost it there. And the integral is hence convergent.

Comment: Exactly. I suppose my comment is tantamount to a real answer, anyway, so I expanded it some below.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt[n]x}~dx~=~n!~$ In this case, $n=2,~$ so your sum converges to a positive value lesser than $2$, since the lower integration limit is $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: @Lucian Interesting result :) ! Thanks.

Comment: See [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $N$th partial sum of the series is
$$\sum_{n = 1}^N \int_n^{n + 1} e^{-\sqrt{x}} \,dx = \int_1^{N + 1} e^{-\sqrt{x}} \,dx.$$
But in the limit $N \to \infty$ the right-hand side converges, because $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{x}} \,dx$ does: One can also evaluate it directly using the substitution $x = u^2$ followed by i.b.p.

(We don't need both directions here, but the convergence of the sum and integral are equivalent because the integrand is positive.)

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: $e^{-\sqrt{x}}>e^{-x}$ on $[1,\infty)$

Comment: Cheers, Michael, I managed to confuse this with a similar problem I answered today, I've fixed the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to notice that for every $n \int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx \leq e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ because the integrand is a monotone decreasing function. So the sum is upperbounded by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ which again converges by integral test: $\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{x}}dx = 2 \int_{1}^{\infty}t e^{-t}dt$